# How to maintian database for ranking system reseting it periodically while saving old data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to maintain a database for gaming tournament ranking system in which the ranking data is to be reset every 3 months but the old ranking is to be saved as well. Can anyone suggest me how I should that? Should I create a new table for each ranking period or should I maintain all those data in single table and check them using time constraint?

Comment: Those are two excellent options. Depending on your specific implementation one of them might be better, but as you have not specified anything more in that sense, we cannot possibly argue one way or the other....

Comment: Maybe store in a single table with partition? You can partition by the season.

Comment: @iamsleepy It seems like a good solution. Can you provide any reference on how partition is done and how data is selected from such partition?

Comment: I think the best reference would be the mysql documentation[link](https://dev.mysql.com). The database engine will handle which partition to be selected. But beware, there are certain limitations when partitioning a table especially involving `Innodb` foreign key reference. You can `google` it though, there are many tutorials. So this solution might or might not suitable with you.

Comment: If you are expecting less than a million to one or two million rows for the entire table, I suggest you go with what you had in mind. Or, you can number the season put already ended season in one table and the active one in another table. So, you'll have only two tables.